# injective homomorphism of local rings and completions

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-completions

Assume that $f:A\to B$ is an injective and local homomorphism between two local rings. Let $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ be respectively the completions of $A$ and $B$ with respect the maximal ideals. Then we have an induced (continuous) homomorphism $\hat f:\hat A\to \hat B$;

> Is $\hat f$ still injective? If yes, why?

Comment: Are you looking for the general case or when $A,B$ are Noetherian?

Comment: Uhm yes Noetherian. Sorry I forgot to add it

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. I will explain a counterexample.

Take $A = \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. Now consider the ring $B'= \bar{\mathbb{F}}_p [\![ x,y]\!]$. By the countable prime avoidance lemma (see e.g. [Pournaki, Theorem 1.1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwj08Yb417LbAhWEK5oKHVBUD_QQFghUMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.526.8504%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw2VhA8Kz1U3FkzBS2jX48Um)) the ring $B'$ contains uncountably many prime ideals of height $1$:

As $B'$ is an $UFD$, any element $f \in B'$ is contained in a height $1$ prime ideal (namely a principal one). Thus, $(x,y) \subseteq B'$ is contained in the union of all height $1$ primes. But certainly there is not a single height $1$ prime ideal already containing $(x,y)$. This shows that there must be uncountably many such height $1$ prime ideals as else we would have found a contradiction to the above lemma.

Next note that for $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ a prime ideal of height $1$ there are at most finitely many $\mathfrak{p}' \subseteq B'$ of height $1$ such that $A \cap \mathfrak{p}' = \mathfrak{p}$:

Indeed, the ring $B'/\mathfrak{p}B'$ is noetherian of dimension $1$ and any such $\mathfrak{p}'$ is in $1$-to-$1$-correspondence with a minimal prime ideal of $B'/\mathfrak{p}B'$. But a noetherian ring only has a finite number of minimal prime ideals.

Note that $A$ only contains countably many ideals (because it is noetherian and only contains countably many elements). Therefore, we find (uncountably many, but in particular) one prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}' \subseteq B'$ of height $1$ in $B'$ such that $A \cap \mathfrak{p}'=0$.

Thus, take $B= B'/\mathfrak{p}'$. Certainly $B$ is $(x,y)$-complete and by construction the morphism $A \rightarrow B$ is injective. Completing $(x,y)$-adically, we obtain the canonical morphism $\hat{A}= B' \rightarrow B = \hat{B}$ which (again by construction) has the non-trivial kernel $\mathfrak{p}'$.

Comment: under which hypothesis is the injectivity preserved?

Comment: For example if $f(\mathfrak{m}_A)=\mathfrak{m}_B$, then injectivity should be preserved because taking inverse limits is left exact.